# python convert dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I try to convert json to dataframe but I could not find what i want

here is dictionary and result I got

```json
{'20210df12820df1456-ssddsd': {'2': {'num': '2',
                                     'product_name': 'apple',
                                     'product_price': '20900'},
                               'order': {'add_info': None,
                                         'basket_count': '2',
                                         'deli_price': '2500',
                                         'id': 'nhdd@abvc',
                                         'is_member': 'MEMBER',
                                         'mem_type': 'PERSON',
                                         'order_date': '2021-01-28 20:14:56',
                                         'ordernum': '20210df12820df1456-ssddsd',
                                         'pay_price': '43100',
                                         'reserve': '840',
                                         'start_price': '43100',
                                         'total_product_price': '41800',
                                         'used_emoney': '0',
                                         'used_reserve': '0'},
                               'pay_history': [{'add_price': '0',
                                                'deli_price': '2500',
                                                'discount_price': '-1200',
                                                'order_price': '43100',
                                                'pay_date': '2021-01-28 '
                                                            '20:15:14',
                                                'pay_price': '43100',
                                                'pay_type': 'creditcard',
                                                'paymethod': 'C',
                                                'total_price': '41800',
                                                'used_emoney': '0',
                                                'used_reserve': '0'}],
                               'payment': {'card_flag': '0000',
                                           'card_partcancel_code': '00',
                                           'card_state': 'Y',
                                           'in_card_price': '43100',
                                           'pay_date': '2021-01-28 20:15:14',
                                           'pay_status': 'Y',
                                           'paymethod': 'C',
                                           'simple_pay': 'NPY'},
                               'product': {'1': {'num': '1',
                                                 'product_name': 'banana',
                                                 'product_price': '20900'}}}}
```

```
json_data = response.json()
result =json_data['list']
df = pd.DataFrame(result).transpose()
df.head()
```

I would like to make this dictionary to four dataframe.
but i have this result

[image]

I expected like below

```
order = df[['order']]
payment = df[['payment']]
pay_history = df[['pay_history']]
product = df[['product']]
```

something like this.

any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data for each category (order, payment, pay history, product) are organized differently, you should consider iterating through each category, adding additional data (such as `ordernum` for indexing purpose) and putting them in their own list that you will later use to convert them into `DataFrame` object

```
import pandas as pd

json_data = {'20210df12820df1456-ssddsd': {'order': {'ordernum': '20210df12820df1456-ssddsd', 'order_date': '2021-01-28 20:14:56', 'is_member': 'MEMBER', 'start_price': '43100', 'pay_price': '43100', 'deli_price': '2500', 'total_product_price': '41800', 'basket_count': '2', 'id': 'nhdd@abvc', 'mem_type': 'PERSON', 'used_emoney': '0', 'used_reserve': '0', 'add_info': None, 'reserve': '840'}, 'payment': {'paymethod': 'C', 'pay_date': '2021-01-28 20:15:14', 'card_state': 'Y', 'pay_status': 'Y', 'simple_pay': 'NPY', 'card_flag': '0000', 'card_partcancel_code': '00', 'in_card_price': '43100'}, 'pay_history': [{'pay_date': '2021-01-28 20:15:14', 'pay_type': 'creditcard', 'total_price': '41800', 'deli_price': '2500', 'discount_price': '-1200', 'add_price': '0', 'order_price': '43100', 'pay_price': '43100', 'used_reserve': '0', 'used_emoney': '0', 'paymethod': 'C'}], 'product': {'1': {'num': '1', 'product_name': 'banana', 'product_price': '20900'}, '2': {'num': '2', 'product_name': 'apple', 'product_price': '20900'}}}}

order_data = []
payment_data = []
pay_history_data = []
product_data = []

for key in json_data:
    order_data.append(json_data[key]['order'])

    payment = dict(json_data[key]['payment'])
    payment['ordernum'] = key
    pay_history_data.append(payment)

    pay_history = json_data[key]['pay_history']
    if 'pay_history' in json_data[key]:
        for p in pay_history:
            p_clone = dict(p)
            p_clone['ordernum'] = key
            payment_data.append(p_clone)

    product = json_data[key]['product']
    if 'product' in json_data[key]:
        for product_key in product:
            p_clone = dict(product[product_key])
            p_clone['ordernum'] = key
            product_data.append(p_clone)

order_df = pd.DataFrame(order_data)
payment_df = pd.DataFrame(payment_data)
pay_history_df = pd.DataFrame(pay_history_data)
product_df = pd.DataFrame(product_data)
```

Edit: If you're experiencing `KeyError` exception in iterating through `pay_history`, it could be that in some order, there are no `pay_history` key in the json data of that order so you can avoid this by first checking if the key exists in the json file before proceeding to iterating through the `pay_history` (`if 'pay_history' in json_data[key]:`), same thing can be done before iterating through `product` (`if 'product' in json_data[key]:`).

Comment: thx for ur reply. how can i handle this error     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-2b6aa8c524ce> in <module>
     12 
     13     pay_history = result[key]['pay_history']
---> 14     for p in pay_history:
     15         p_clone = dict(p)
     16         p_clone['ordernum'] = key

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @JaehyunLee Ok, I've updated my answer to workaround the error. Let me know if you still have any issues running it

Comment: ok this is other question.  As I tried to join order_df and product_df, there is no key in product_df. I expected that ordernum should be include in product_df.

Comment: @JaehyunLee Ok, I've updated my answer to that `ordernum` is included in `product_df`. Let me know if there are other issues

Answer (score 1):

What you need is pandas json_normalize function.
I wrote some example codes.

```
import pandas as pd

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {'20210df12820df1456-ssddsd': {'order': {'ordernum': '20210df12820df1456-ssddsd', 'order_date': '2021-01-28 20:14:56', 'is_member': 'MEMBER', 
                                                'start_price': '43100', 'pay_price': '43100', 'deli_price': '2500', 'total_product_price': '41800',
                                                'basket_count': '2', 'id': 'nhdd@abvc', 'mem_type': 'PERSON', 'used_emoney': '0', 'used_reserve': '0', 'add_info': None, 'reserve': '840'},
                                      'payment': {'paymethod': 'C', 'pay_date': '2021-01-28 20:15:14', 'card_state': 'Y', 'pay_status': 'Y', 'simple_pay': 'NPY', 'card_flag': '0000', 'card_partcancel_code': '00', 'in_card_price': '43100'}, 
                                      'pay_history': [{'pay_date': '2021-01-28 20:15:14', 'pay_type': 'creditcard', 'total_price': '41800', 'deli_price': '2500', 'discount_price': '-1200', 'add_price': '0', 'order_price': '43100', 'pay_price': '43100', 'used_reserve': '0', 'used_emoney': '0', 'paymethod': 'C'}],
                                      'product': {'1': {'num': '1', 'product_name': 'banana', 'product_price': '20900'}}, '2': {'num': '2', 'product_name': 'apple', 'product_price': '20900'}}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()

order = json_normalize(df['order'])
```

the result will look like:

[image: results]

Comment: what if i want to get ordernum each dataframe ? 

data = {'20210df12820df1456-ssddsd': {'order': {'ordernum': 

because I would like to join order table and product table